# jquery applies the .addClass() before the fadeOut() applied

Tags: jquery

I am doing something like this:

**case**: when i click on add link it should remove the class style on Div and Fadeout and then it should add a class and then fadein. But the problem is it removes the class, then adds class then performs fadeout and fadeIn. Why it is adding the class before fadeout?

here is my code

```
$(function(){
    $('#noti1').click(function() {
        $('#blue').removeClass( "ui-state-highlight").fadeOut(1000, mossawir);

        function mossawir() {
            setTimeout(function() {
                $( "#effect" ).addClass( "newClass" );
            }, 1500);
        }

        $('#blue').addClass("ui-state-error").fadeIn('slow');
     });
});
```

I even tried a more simple way:

```
$(function() {
    $('#noti1').click(function() {
        $('#blue').removeClass( "ui-state-highlight").fadeOut('slow');
        $('#blue').addClass("ui-state-error").fadeIn('slow');
    });
});
```

Comment: I didn't have time to create an answer from your code, but it sounds like you could use the queu feature in jQuery to do exactly what you want. read about it here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.queue/

Comment: hi.. if i dont want to use queue? is their any other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's adding the class before you fade out because that's exactly what you told it to do.

jQuery's normal methods aren't processed as part of the animation queue, they're executed immediately.

You could try:

```
$('#blue')
   .removeClass('ui-state-highlight')
   .fadeOut(1000, mossawir)
   .queue(function() {
       $(this).addClass('ui-state-error')
       $(this).dequeue();
   })
   .fadeIn('slow');
```

to insert the class change as part of the animation queue.

NB: this method preserves your existing completion callback (`mossawir`) to add the `newClass` effect once the `.fadeOut` had completed.  The other answers don't allow for that (yet).

Comment: is it possible not to use queue? any other option?

Comment: @mossawir why not use queue? this is exactly what it's designed for.

Comment: @Alnitak.. thank you very much.. i am kind a afraid from the complexity of the code. i might perform some other operations in future, i want every thing to be clear. i am kinda new to Jquery

Comment: @mossawir jQuery animation queueing doesn't get any _easier_ (or clearer) than this.  `.queue()` is nothing more than a way of inserting your own functions into the chain of animation sequences.

Answer (score 3):

That's because animation methods like [fadeOut()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/) and [fadeIn()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/) are *asynchronous*: they return immediately and perform their work later.

Since asynchronous methods return before they complete, they usually take a *callback* function argument that gets called when they *do* complete. In your case, you only need to run the `fadeIn` animation when the `fadeOut` effect completes, i.e. in its callback:

```
$("#noti1").click(function() {
    $("#blue").removeClass("ui-state-highlight").fadeOut("slow", function() {
        $(this).addClass("ui-state-error").fadeIn("slow");
    });
});
```

Comment: problem remain the same. it applies the addclass then fade out:S

Comment: @mossawir, strange, it should remove the class, fade out, then add the class and fade in. What's your browser?

Comment: i am using Chrome and Firefox.. tested on Both :S